# Cannot find -lfreeglut codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, glut, glew, freeglut

I just tried to setup freeglut in my codeblocks 20 64-bit pre-packaged mingw-gnu-compiler, following popular youtube tutorials, 
I created the glut project in codeblocks, and tried to compile, it gives error

```
||=== Build: Debug in SnakeGame (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld.exe||cannot find -lfreeglut|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 3 second(s)) ===|
```

What's wrong?

Comment: ***What's wrong?*** Where did you install freeglut?

Comment: Where means what?

Comment: @drescherjm https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPcnymtP2SE

Comment: The error is telling you that the linker can't find the freeglut library you installed. With that said I don't like the video instruction to put files inside your Code::Blocks install folder. In my opinion this is a bad practice.

Comment: @drescherjm In your opinion, how to install freeglut in codeblocks?

Comment: Create a folder somewhere on your hard drive something like c:\Programming\libs where you expand the headers, libraries and dlls possibly in 3 separate folders. Then follow these instructions: [https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/)